# Plurals in phonetic spelling

Tags: grammatical-number, phonetics

If I spell *doing* as *doin'* then how should I spell *doings*?
Would it simply be *doin's*?

Comment: For a start, I would **not** phonetically spell *doing* as *doin'* - the *g* is pronounced, at least in BrE.

Comment: @TrevorD you may be in a [minority](https://www.google.com/search?q=whatcha+doin).

Comment: @TrevorD Do you perhaps mean that the suffix *-ing* is pronounced with a /g/ in *some BrE dialects*? It was my impression that RP is /ɪŋ/, and that /ɪn/, standard in the 18th century,  is still common colloquially in all regions.

Comment: The answer is Yes, that's the way it's done. However, this is **not** phonetic spelling. There is [such a thing as phonetic spelling](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/modestproposal.pdf), and this is not it. This is technically called "[Eye Dialect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_dialect)".

Comment: What's "doings?"

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg *Doings* are what dogs leave on pavements, among [other things](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/doing?q=doings).

Comment: [This ad](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffUDDYYIX04) has twelve _How-ya-doin's_.

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, to your first question. But I'm not familiar with and do not understand the phonetic symbols.

Comment: Depends completely on the context, of course. One does *not* in fact usually spell "doing" as "doin'" -- that's a deliberate attempt to de-formalize the register, and only used in specific contexts. So whether you use the standard "doings" or the de-formalizing "doin's" also depends on context.

Answer (score 3):

How you doin'? [Friends]  Ha!

---

I would distinguish the usage of "doin" from "doin's".  The context in which "doin's" is the word to use is likely to be much different, and much less frequent, than "doin'", which will come up in casual conversation with some frequency, as with - "Watcha doin'?"  The usage of "doin's" is likely to be entirely unrelated.

---

'Doin's would often be dialect, as with literature.  The best known example is possibly from "The Turmoil" (1915), by Booth Tarkington.

"Ev'ything got look spick an' span fo' the big doin's to-night," Bibbs's guide explained, chuckling. "Yessuh, we got big doin's to-night! Big doin's!"

http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1098/1098-h/1098-h.htm

---

Certainly, it shouldn't be difficult to find numerous examples from works in the pickaninny dialect.

"Like her pap, all big noise and no big doin's."

"Imitation of Life", Fannie Hurst

http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/691242.Imitation_of_Life

---

However, I surely do not think usage need be racial caricature.  One ought be careful, though, to ensure that usage captures a character's voice, avoiding the perception that it is contrived, or otherwise forced.

"Big doin's" is in the language as a rural, country expression.

"Ham Nation", "Big Doin's in Starkville"

[Oops.  I don't have the reputation to use this third link:]

youtu.be/m-NLr4fZ4sI

---

I reckon those examples ought help.  I'm fixin' to chow down the wife's fine cookin' here in a bit, so got to go.  Catch y'all later.